# How to create a output-depending sliderInput?

Tags: r, shiny

Diving deeper into Shiny possibilities, I'm once more facing a difficulty I can't overcome. So looking for help :)

I have a dataset with a number of `country`, each of them having a more or less different set of `partner` countries. For each of these combination of `country` and `partner`, I have a `quantity` assigned to a number of `year`.

Here is a sample:

```
data <- data.frame(country = c("Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde"), 
                   partner = c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"),
                   year = c(1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2002, 2003, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017),
                   quantity = c(9, 9, 9, 7, 14, 7, 6, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 10, 5, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10, 31, 62, 31, 23, 23, 27, 27, 27, 25, 25, 25, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 38, 38, 38, 80, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 49, 49, 49, 46, 46, 46, 46))
```

I'd like to create a shiny app where I can choose a `partner` for the selected `country`, with a reactive sliderInput that only shows the years for which there is a quantity for this country/partner combination.

So far, I have managed to create a reactive second selecInput that allows me to choose a `partner` among the possible ones for the selected `country`, but I can't figure out how to make the sliderInput reactive.

I've attempted a number of things, including an `observe` statement based on  either `countryOutput` or `countryInput`, but it does not work. In the above example, this means that the sliderInput should go from 1996 to 2003 for Angola/France, from 2000 to 2003 for Angola/Ireland etc.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks :)

Here is my code so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Define UI for application that draws time-series
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
titlePanel("Dummy shiny"),

# Create filters 
fluidRow(

  column(3,
         selectInput("countryInput", label = h4("Select country:"), 
                     as.character(unique(data$country)))),
  column(3,
         uiOutput("partnerOutput")),
  column(6,
         sliderInput("dateInput", label = h4("Select time range:"),
                     min = min(data$year), 
                     max = max(data$year), 
                     value = c(min(data$year), max(data$year), step = 1),
                     sep = "")
  )
),
plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw the wanted time-series
server <- function(input, output) {
output$partnerOutput <- renderUI({
  selectInput("partnerInput", label = h4("Pick partner:"), choices = as.character(data[data$country==input$countryInput,"partner"]))
})

filtered <- reactive({
  data %>%
    filter(country == input$countryInput,
           partner == input$partnerInput,
           year >= input$dateInput[1],
           year <= input$dateInput[2]
    )
})

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = year, y = quantity)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


data <- data.frame(country = c("Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde", "Cabo Verde"), 
                   partner = c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"),
                   year = c(1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2002, 2003, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017),
                   quantity = c(9, 9, 9, 7, 14, 7, 6, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 10, 5, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10, 31, 62, 31, 23, 23, 27, 27, 27, 25, 25, 25, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 38, 38, 38, 80, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 49, 49, 49, 46, 46, 46, 46))

peryear = data %>%
    group_by(country, partner) %>%
    summarise(min = min(year), max = max(year))
peryear

# Define UI for application that draws time-series
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Dummy shiny"),

    # Create filters 
    fluidRow(

        column(3,
               selectInput("countryInput", label = h4("Select country:"), 
                           as.character(unique(data$country)))),
        column(3,
               uiOutput("partnerOutput")),
        column(6,
               uiOutput("dynamicdates")
        )
    ),
    plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw the wanted time-series
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$partnerOutput <- renderUI({
        print(as.character(data[data$country==input$countryInput,"partner"]))
        selectInput("partnerInput", label = h4("Pick partner:"), choices = unique(data$partner), selected = unique(data$partner)[1])
    })

    filtered <- reactive({
        data %>%
            filter(country == input$countryInput,
                   partner == input$partnerInput,
                   year >= input$dateInput[1],
                   year <= input$dateInput[2]
            )
    })

    output$dynamicdates <- renderUI({

        if(is.null(input$partnerInput)) {
            return(NULL)
        }

        filterdf <- peryear %>%
            filter(country == input$countryInput) %>%
            filter(partner == input$partnerInput)

        sliderInput("dateInput", label = h4("Select time range:"),
                    min = filterdf$min, 
                    max = filterdf$max,
                    value = c(filterdf$min, filterdf$max, step = 1),
                    sep = "")
    })

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = year, y = quantity)) +
            geom_point() +
            geom_smooth() +
            labs(x = "", y = "") +
            scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Use `renderUI` to do that. I created a grouped data.frame to check the max and min values of each year per partner and take that as min and max values of the `sliderInput`. Also preselected one item for PartnerInput to prevent an error.

Comment: Oh woah! That's great, thank you very much. This works very well and the only issue I see is that the the list of `partnerInput`includes all of them, not only those that are possible for the selected `country`. Is it possible to base both `choices`and `selected` on the actual output?

Comment: yes, with the same technique, create a dataframe,a conditional filter for that dataframe and use renderUI for create the input on the server side. server side rendering is pretty good for doing dependend stuff :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that :)

Comment: good luck, if you need help don´t hesitate to open a new question. I´m often here to help